# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: in Visual studio code

Tags: python, database, csv, matplotlib, int

Dont understand why it wont read this csv file correclty

```
import os
import csv


CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'sitka_weather_2018_full.csv')

with open(file_path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    highs = []
    for row in reader:
        high = int(row[8])
        highs.append(high)


    print(highs)
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/ CrashCourse Python Notes/Chapter 16 CC/Downloading Date/csv format/highs_lows.py in 
     18     highs = []
     19     for row in reader:
---> 20         high = int(row[8])
     21         highs.append(high)
     22 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

any help would be great

Comment: It looks like that cell is the empty string. Is that valid or is your data corrupt? What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: it was running just fine before but when I trired to change  string into an integer i ran into this problem. there is data there just not getting through for some reason. im about to give up on this stupid book anyways.

Comment: the first answer if you want to use next you've to use iter or you have to create loop the for items and put next into this loop

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the CSV column 8 is empty, you need to decide whether that is an error that should terminate your program or something you can recover from. The following code logs the error and continues processing. As a minimum this is a good way to debug the problem.

```
import os
import csv

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'sitka_weather_2018_full.csv')

with open(file_path) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    highs = []
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, 2):
        # Ignore empty lines
        if not row:
            continue
        # Get high column as int. If error, log and ignore
        try:
            high = int(row[8])
            highs.append(high)
        except ValueError:
            print("Error line {}: {}".format(i, row))
        except IndexError:
            # Wrong number of columns, this file is corrupted. 
            print("Invalid column count line {}: {}".format(i, row))
            exit(2)
    print(highs)
```

Comment: Great that worked! Im not sure how though , which is very frustrating. Do you know any good sources to learn how to read and run CSV files with python? Im not having the best luck with these out of date examples 'Python Crash Course' includes. Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately I don't know which resources are the best for learning. In this case, the error text said you had a ValueError so I just wrapped the conversion in a try/except to figure out how to handle it. This is an important part of dealing with input - you need to have a plan for everything that goes wrong. For instance, what if its an empty line? I'll add another example for that.

Comment: Great! I'll remember that for the future, thanks again for the help.